# Unsubscribe not working on NgOnDestroy

Tags: angular, angular2-observables, behaviorsubject

this is the code in the service where i've got the BehaviorSubject

```
  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<Customer>(getEmptyCustomer());
  public currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
```

and this is method

```
  public passCustomer(data: Customer) {
    this.messageSource.next(data);
  }
```

In a component i use passCustomer

```
  public passDataToNewContract(customer: Customer) {
    this.customerService.passCustomer(customer);
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/nuoviClienti/aggiungiCliente']);
  }
```

Indeed i want to pass the data to a sibling component and it worked.
But there is a problem when i'll tried to unsubscribed

```
  public ngOnInit() {
    this.alive = this.customerService.currentMessage.subscribe((message) => {
      console.log(message);
    });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.alive.unsubscribe();
  }
```

It does not work. I tried to change component for activated ngOnDestroy but every times angular prints the datas.
I also tried the method with takeUntil but nothing.

Comment: Did you 'implements OnDestroy' ?

Comment: does ngOnDestroy get called?

Comment: Yes, ngOnDestroy get called

Comment: I have the same issue.  I am subscribing to observables and events successfully in my custom child component during its initialization, but the unsubscribe requests is not taking effect even though I can see it is being called within ngOnDestroy (and there are no errors in the console).  The net effect is that each time I revisit a page with that child component it is reacting multiple times to event/observable changes.  If I put all the same logic in the parent page, then all of the unsubscribe logic works fine.

Note this is within the context of an Ionic project, which is using Angular 4

Comment: Interesting scenario which needs deep debugging. In other words, we've decided to use [until-destroy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngneat/until-destroy) on a large project and it works just fine so far (more than 6 months later). Maybe you should give it a try and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think previous subscription still holds the stream so you need to clear it before destroying the component. Kill your subscription once you close your tab. One way to do that is:

```
someSubscription: Subscription
ngOnInit() {
      this.customerService.passCustomer();
      this.someSubscription = this.customerService.currentMessage.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    });
}


ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.someSubscription) {
        this.someSubscription .unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

or in another way like

```
 destroy$ = new Subject();

 ngOnInit() {
      let empty = [];
      this.customerService.passCustomer(empty);
      this.customerService.currentDeviceList
       .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)) // takUntil from rxjs
       .subscribe(data => {
           if(data.length !=0){
             console.log(data)
           }    
    });
  }

 ngOnDestroy(){
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete(); // always call complete for guaranteed subscription removal
 }
```